# Unable to download complete file in android app

Tags: java, android

following is my code,

**From Activity class**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
        // Create a new Messenger for the communication back
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
        intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.abc.ezy.asia/E-MobApps/op.apk"));
        intent.putExtra("urlpath", "http://www.abc.ezy.asia/E-MobApps/op.apk");
        startService(intent);
```

**I have overrided  Service Class method onHandle Event**

```
 // DownloadService Class
 @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra("urlpath");
        String fileName = data.getLastPathSegment();
        File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),fileName);
        if (output.exists()) {
            output.delete();
        }
        InputStream stream = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
            byte dataB[] = new byte[1024];
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            int next = -1;
            while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
                fos.write(next);
            }
            fos.flush();
            result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Messenger messenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.arg1 = result;
            msg.obj = output.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                messenger.send(msg);
            } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
                Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In above code I used File Streams & Input stream reader for downloading 
when tried to download html file then complete file was downloaded to my sdcard.But when I tried for APK. The File downloaded of 2.2 mb instead of 2.4 mb Parsing problem is there. Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't think your code will discriminate based on the file type. Please make sure your know the exact size of the APK (could be 2.2) or it may be possible that the file is corrupted. Why not try with some other apk files on web ?

Comment: Thanks. But when i download the file via browser it downloads completely

Comment: so what happens when you try to open(install) the file you downloaded from App?  Does it show that it is incomplete or corrupted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this piece of code :

```
                URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());                  
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                input.close();
                result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
```